# Synchronize animation in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have single javascript animation code on single Onclick() function and condition is that second animation should not start unless first finish and Onclick() function is called from xml file. Need rapper javascript where I can handled this scenario.

javascript like this :

```
Function Onclik() {
    trans.delay=3000 ms;
    trans.duration=3000 ms;
    obj1.trnslate();
    Play();                   // Each Play() will do the animation
    trans.delay=4000 ms;      // Should not start work unless previous Play() finish. 
    trans.duration=4000 ms;
    obj2.rotate();
    Play();                  
    trans.delay=5000 ms;      // Should not start work unless previous Play() finish.
    trans.duration=5000 ms;
    obj3.scale();
    Play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout()` to insert an delay of the duration of animation1.

EG:

Animation1 is of 5 second. so

```
setTimeout(function() {
  // Do something after 5 seconds
  //Here insert animation2's code
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Onclick() function is called from xml file. Need rapper javascript where I can handled this scenario.